# MIB translation with pysnmp (loading error)

Tags: python, pysnmp

The idea is to translate OIDs to MIB object names and vise versa including getting the names of enumerated values using pysnmp.

I found this ['PDU var-binds to MIB objects'](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/smi/manager/browsing-mib-tree.html#pdu-var-binds-to-mib-objects) example, but when I'm trying to load different MIBs (example varBinds part is commented, so no problem in there), NMS in particular, I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyasn1/type/univ.py", line 227, in prettyIn
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'
```

[NMS MIB](http://www.circitor.fr/Mibs/Html/T/TNMS-NBI-MIB.php) and all three its imported modules have their compiled .py variants in .pysnmp/mibs folder. NET-SNMPs snmptranslate app translates OIDs without errors.

What can be the reason of loading issue, some MIB inconsistency?

**Addition**:

Packages were upgraded up to pysnmp-4.3.10, pyasn1-0.3.7, pysmi-0.1.4.
Successfully tried original example without any addition to code, except used MIB list, with randomly found two another MIBs which also includes imported SNMPv2-TC and RFC1155-SMI. Problem arise in loading part of the code only when NMS MIB is added to loadModules list.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your pyasn1, pysnmp and pysmi packages to the latest released versions.

If it does not help, can you come up with a simple reproducer?

Does this error happen to any particular MIB?

Comment: Thanks, updated packages and tried with another MIBs. It seems that it is some strange MIB. Results added to description.